# Single icon is not shown in chrome when using inline svg

Tags: html, google-chrome, inline-svg

I am using inline svg like this

`<use xlink:href=""></use>`

but for some reason one particular icon is not shown in Chrome (but it's shown in Firefox and ios Safari), other icons are visible in Chrome.

Here's icon itself (it is exported from icomoon)

`<symbol id="icon-phone" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<title>phone</title>
<path d="M22 20c-2 2-2 4-4 4s-4-2-6-4-4-4-4-6 2-2 4-4-4-8-6-8-6 6-6 6c0 4 4.109 12.109 8 16s12 8 16 8c0 0 6-4 6-6s-6-8-8-6z"></path>
</symbol>`

I've also tried to use just *href* instead of *xlink:href*, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<symbol id="icon-phone" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
```

and

```
</symbol>
```

wrapper and replace it with

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32">
```

and

```
</svg>
```